# Import text file using terminal in program C programming

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program in C that I will run from the terminal and will accept as input  some lines from a file for example "error.log". How can I do that?

Command Example:
./prog < error.log

Comment: That's what argc and argv are for

Comment: I think you're referring to *nix "pipes", which means you read from stdin?

Comment: That's input redirection, same code as reading from user (keyboard) input. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: You don't have to write _anything_, just loop over `argv`, skipping the value at index 0. The file is there.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is example to start.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 256

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char buf[BLOCK_SIZE];
    size_t bytes;

    while(!feof(stdin)) {
        bytes = fread(buf, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, stdin);
        fwrite(buf, 1, bytes, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It just prints out the file you specify as `./prog < filetoprint.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the shell syntax for input redirection — that is `< filename` — then you don't actually have to do anything special. You just read from stdin (e.g. plain `gets` or `scanf` instead of `fgets` or `fscanf`).

If you want to take the names of files as arguments, then, as the commenters have indicated, you can find those arguments in the `argv` array passed to your `main()` function, starting at index `1`.